Extract password protected 7z files using Powershell
I am trying to extract bunches of 7z files.
I was able to get these two sets of Powershell script from other Stackoverflow posts, but none of them seem to work.
$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$zipFile = '"F:\NHSFTP\WH_20240803_1.7z"'
$zipFilePassword = "xYxYxYx"
$command = "& $7ZipPath e -oe:\ -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command


$7ZipPath = '"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"'
$zipFile = '"F:\NHSFTP\WH_20240803_1.7z"'
$zipFilePassword = "xYxYxYx"
$command = "&amp; $7ZipPath e -oW:\ADMINISTRATION -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile"
iex $command

What am I missing?
I am also trying to open multiple 7z files, not just one.
Do I express something like this?
$zipFile = '"F:\NHSFTP\*.7z"'

Update
Is this what I need to run (updated script)?
$7ZipPath = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
$zipFile = 'F:\NHSFTP\WH_20240803_1.7z'
$zipFilePassword = 'xYxYxYx'
& $7ZipPath e -oe:\ -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile


Why do you need Invoke-Expression? Just put & $7ZipPath e -oe:\ -y -tzip -p$zipFilePassword $zipFile on its own line. Also, don't quote anything you have in variables, PS would take care of it. I.e. $7ZipPath = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'. No double quotes.

Also, please focus on a single issue you're having.

@n0rd Thank you for your feedback. I updated the post with your suggestion. Can you please review the updated script and let me know if anything is wrong?

You might use a tool like Process Monitor to learn the actual parameters used to initialize the external process, and that can show you what might be wrong. Besides, modern AIs are very good at writing such scripts and they know how to properly quote file paths while you might be confused.

7z multithreads these days which is cool

There is no reason to use Invoke-Expression here, I suggest creating a function that you can easily reuse later on. Also 7zip is capable of detecting the compression algorithm so you could just remove -tzip as argument.
function Expand-7zip {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute(
        'PSAvoidUsingPlainTextForPassword', '')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string] $Path,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $OutputPath,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Password
    )

    begin {
        $7z = 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
    }
    process {
        $params = @(
            'e'
            if ($OutputPath) {
                '-o' + $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($OutputPath)
            }
            '-y'
            $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
        )

        if ($Password) {
            $Password | & $7z @params
            return
        }

        & $7z @params
    }
}

Then you can use it like:
Expand-7zip F:\NHSFTP\WH_20240803_1.7z -OutputPath E:\ -Password xYxYxYx

And for extracting multiple files you can pipe the output from Get-ChildItem to this function (considering in this example all files have the same password):
Get-ChildItem F:\NHSFTP\ -Filter *.7z | Expand-7zip -Password xxxxx


I suspect this will break if the password contains a character that gets (mis)interpreted by the parser.

@Bill_Stewart can you think of one that could cause that?

Possibly one that includes the " character?

@Bill_Stewart thanks for that, you were right. The way to pass-in the password is thru piping, it handles escaping correctly
